# MySQL SET NAMES - working mechanizm explanation?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I recenly had problem in importing latin1_swedish database into new one. Somone made Latin1 Database to store Latin2 characters. It was all working till I made database dump and wanted to import it to another database.

It's really complicated. In the end I corrected sql dump to proper ISO-8859-2 Encoded file with all characters displaying correctly. Still import into tables with Latin2 encoding didn't work, all special characters were lost (maybe its a PHPMyAdmin bug?).

Converting file to UTF-8 encoding and changing table encoding to utf8_general_ci imported everything correctly.

Next, whole PHP site uses and displays ISO-8859-2 characters (its old PHPBB forum).

While connecting to Database I use "SET NAMES latin2" command to change encoding.

To my surprise, page displays as proper ISO-8859-2.

If table is UTF-8 and Set names is latin2. Does MySQL connection convert characters into ISO-8859-2 before returning them???

(didnt know if I shoud write it all or not. Edit it if I put too much not needed info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SET NAMES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html) effectively sets how the data is translated before being stored or after recalled, prior to presenting to the client. For the case of storage, the character set definition of the column is the ultimate determining factor (if it differs from table, and database character set definition). See this informative blog post about [encoding in MySQL](http://www.bluebox.net/about/blog/2009/07/mysql_encoding/).

Comment: So basicly, if I retrive data from UTF encoded table while SET NAMES Latin2 is in effect. Returned data will be in ISO-8859-2? Or still in UTF?

Comment: If the data is stored as UTF-8 and SET NAMES Latin2 is issued, the data SELECTed will be converted to Latin2 prior to being presented to the client. You should note that this conversion on every SELECT can cause performance degradation if massive amounts of data need to be recalled and converted.